# YII framework how to run a sqlite schema?

Tags: php, sqlite, yii

I've edited a `schema.sqlite.sql` file, but how can I run it in YII framework to update the tables?

Because if I create a model in the gii tool, I get an error that there are no table created, thats why I need to run the `schema.sqlite.sql`, to update the file `testdrive.db`

Answer (score 0):

Gii uses the dabase connection defined in protected/config/main.php. So whatever is in the database connection defined is usable to generate models.

you can use [this fire fox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) for viewing and editing sqlite databases.